# Java eclipse, why JVM crash?

Tags: java, crash, jvm

I have latest eclipse version.
I cant run most of codes who contains:
Fullscreen(true);
Contains mp3/mp4 files.
Even if these codes works well on my OTHER computer.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION (0xc000001d) at pc=0x000007feef805c01, pid=2660, tid=0x00000000000016ec
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_121-b13) (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.121-b13 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcr120.dll+0x95c01]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\44\Bandymai\hs_err_pid2660.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

And this aswell.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: MediaException: MEDIA_INACCESSIBLE : c
    at javafx.scene.media.Media.<init>(Media.java:409)
    at SpalvosFonas.MediaMP4.start(MediaMP4.java:26)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application SpalvosFonas.MediaMP4
```

How to solve? I have windows7 64bit.

Comment: you should take a look at C:\44\Bandymai\hs_err_pid2660.log

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8150261

Comment: Please share the complete logs from hs_error file from C:\44\Bandymai\hs_err_pid2660.lo

Comment: Reinstalled OS. Dont have anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application uses the native lib `msvcr120.dll` (Microsoft Visual Studio 2013) and that crashes for whatever reasons. Maybe the other computer has a different version of this dll, maybe a different java version.

I'd check if both environments are the same and try to update as much as possible.

Comment: I found:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8150261
Need to switch OS

Comment: It is not necessarily same issue, crashing in the same location of java call to msvcr120.dll method...